# Recursively enumerable language of Turing machines

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

If you have the language $L_{h}=\{M_{i} | (\exists z \in \sum ^{*}) M_{i}\text{ halts  on  some  input } z\}$

where $M_{i}$ are Turing machines, is $L_{h}$ recursively enumerable?

I'm fairly certain it is, but I'm having issues proving that to be the case.
The way I understand RE languages is that they CAN be infinite, which this language most certainly is, but I have no idea where to go from there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you prove that $\{i\mid M_i \text{ halts on the empty tape}\}$ is r.e.?

Comment: yes, that is how I went about proving that $L_{h}$ is infinite.
-sorry, didnt read the last part. that would get me the answer, but that is what I dont know how to do.

Comment: How about proving that $\{x \mid M_i\text{ halts on input }x \}$ is r.e. for every $i$?

Comment: another edit:
yes, i can prove it is r.e, however, $\{i | M_{i} halts\ on\ empty\ tape\}$ is a subset of $L_{h}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- First, is the language of all Turing machines enumerable?
- Consider a language $L_i = \{M_i \mid M_i \text{ halts on some input }\}$. Its size is at most $1$, how to "enumerate it"?
- Run in parallel $L_i$ for all Turing machines, and if some of $L_i$ finishes, output its unique element.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$